# cy.url not returning a string as expected

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, regression-testing

Prior to switching to using a hash router, I had been implementing the `cy.url` command frequently to assure that links were navigating to the right URL addresses throughout the application. Now that we are using hash routing `cy.url` no longer yields a string, instead it is yielding a function. Any ideas how to work around this or reasons this is happening?

I was getting errors through out the cypress test runner like:

> AssertionError: object tested must be an array, an object, or a string, but undefined given

so I logged the typeof result `console.log(typeof(cy.url))` and got function printed to the console.

```
cy.get(dataCyButtonAttribute)
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
  console.log(typeof(cy.url))
  cy.url().then(url => {
    const categoryId = url.split(`${linkType}/`)[1]
    const category = url.split('admin/')[1]
    expect(category).to.contain(linkType)
    expect(categoryId).to.equal('new')
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example GitHub repository that shows this behavior? I tried to reproduce this using your example, but `cy.url` always yields a string for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should yield a string:

```
const returnedUrl = null
cy.url().then(url => {
  returnedUrl = url;
});
```

Cypress commands are asynchronous and must be followed by `.then()` in order to yield useful return values.

You can refer to this Github issue for more info:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2150

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. And my solution as below.

```
      cy.url().then(($base_url) => {   
        let id =  $base_url.substr($base_url.lastIndexOf('/'),$base_url.length) 
        cy.log("The id is " + id);
       })
```

It works for me.